In CMake, how do I assure linking against sometimes-separate parts of the C++ standard libray (fs, stacktrace)?
In principle, a provider of an implementation of the C++ standard library does not have to bundle everything in a single library/archive file; and, indeed, G++ is (in)famous for doing that, having for a long time required the specification of -lstdc++fs.
These days, we also have the stack trace library, which may need a separate linked library. But, then again, with the recent Release of GCC 14.1, we hear that:
`libstdc++exp.a` library now includes all symbols for the Filesystem TS and the 
experimental symbols for the C++23 `std::stacktrace` class, so `-lstdc++exp` can
be used instead of `-lstdc++fs`.

How do I account all of this, in terms of CMake commands, to ensure my executable is linked against all relevnat libraries - with syntax which would work both for GCC and other compilers, and for all (recent) GCC versions including 14.x ?
So far, I've not used stacktrace myself, and in my CMakeFiles, I've been writing:
target_link_libraries(my_executable PRIVATE stdc++fs)

and it's not clear to me whether I need to change that (to stdc++exp), or add another item etc.

Arguably, I've never figured out how to make cmake even remotely portable -- so, I just use lines like target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} pthread systemd ${Boost_LIBRARIES}) target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${Protobuf_LIBRARIES}) target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${OPENSSL_LIBRARIES}) target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} atomic). I'll ditch cmake entirely next chance I get anyway, to simplify things...

@ChristianStieber: Ah, well, you're kind of doing it wrong. My CMakeLists are typically quite portable, and I stick to modern CMake with target_link_libraries() to define dependencies. Let me elaborate a little on what I have so far.
